# Atheros AR9285 / Lenovo G560 wireless not working after installing 13.04

Tags: wireless, lenovo, atheros

I had Ubuntu 12.04 initially installed on my laptop. I upgraded to 12.10 then 13.04. 
Everything worked fine, including wireless.
After adding a new memory card ( I only had 2 gb and one memory slot free) my wireess stopped working.
I backed up all my data and reinstallled Ubuntu 13.04.
Everything works fine except wireess.
I bought this laptop in 2010 from Japan.
It has Intel Core i5 CPU M 450 @2.40 Ghz * 4
3,7 Gb RAM
os type 64 bit
The output of iwconfig:
    eth0      no wireless extensions.

```
lo        no wireless extensions.


wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
```

The output of rfkill list all:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The output of lshw -C network:

```
   *-network                      description: Wireless interface
   product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: 78:e4:00:7d:fe:fa
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.8.0-19-generic                    firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:d6400000-d640ffff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 02
   serial: 88:ae:1d:2b:36:ac
   size: 100Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical   tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.2.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
   resources: irq:41 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d2410000-d2410fff memory:d2400000-d240ffff memory:d2420000-d243ffff
```

The wi-fi network appears as disconnected ( it's greyed out) Strangely enough I see a wifi network ( not mine) but not mine or the rest. That network doesn't require a password . I click on it, try to connect and i get an error message: 
    failed to connect to xxxxx ... 32) The access point/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/0 
was not in the scan list.
Someone help please

Answer (score 0):

I've had same issue - it is VERY LOW LEVEL - see my post on it here:

[info about wireless being greyed out on Lubuntu 13.04, after an OS upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377948/partially-solved-info-about-wireless-being-greyed-out-on-lubuntu-13-04-af)

Try that - wish you luck

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I tried everything you mentioned, in the right order. First the a,b,c,d steps.Nothing changed. Then I did rfkill list - nothing was blocked. un-ticked enable networking, ticked back...nothing.